# Get rid of repetitive JSDoc type declarations in object literal

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

While my question is more general and not directly related to automation tests architecture, POM, and any framework I will use some real-world examples.

In my test framework I use Cypress and POM architecture. Please see example of page object:

```
export const homePage = getPageObjectProxy({
  /** @type {Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>} */ 
  searchField: 'input',
  /** @type {Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>} */ 
  logOutButton: '[data-testid=logout-button]',
  /** @type {Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>} */ 
  modeDropdown: '[data-testid=mode-dropdown]',

  setMode(name) {
    this.modeDropdown.click();
    this.modeDropdown.children().contains(name).click();
  }
});
```

Proxy function (as you can see I change type of `string` properties to `Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>`):

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} pageObject a regular page object
 * @returns {T} proxied page object
 */
export const getPageObjectProxy = pageObject => new Proxy(pageObject, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (typeof target[prop] === 'string') {
      return cy.get(target[prop]);
    }
    return target[prop];
  }
});
```

As a result after applying proxy I get an object with DOM elements (instead of selectors) and methods. These works perfectly (IDE intellisense also works).

With this approach I see 1 drawback. **I must explicitly set type for each object property** using JSDoc:

```
/** @type {Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>} */
```

I am curious is it possible using JSDoc somehow avoid this repetitive `@type` definitions for each property?

Comment: Well the type of `getPageObjectProxy` looks wrong. It returns a different shape than it takes. (If this were TypeScript, I'd use `Record<string, string>` and `Record<string, Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>>>`, or a generic and a mapped type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy (used conditional mapped types in JSDoc):

```
/**
 * @template T
 * @param {T} pageObject a page object with string selectors
 * @returns {{[key in keyof T]: T[key] extends string ? Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<HTMLElement>> : T[key]}} page object with DOM elements
 */
export const getPageObjectProxy = pageObject => new Proxy(pageObject, {
  get(target, prop) {
    if (typeof target[prop] === 'string') {
      return cy.get(target[prop]);
    }
    return target[prop];
  }
});
```

Page object (used proxied object instead of `this` in the methods):

```
export const homePage = getPageObjectProxy({
  searchField: 'input',
  logOutButton: '[data-testid=logout-button]',
  modeDropdown: '[data-testid=mode-dropdown]',

  setMode(name) {
    homePage.modeDropdown.click();
    homePage.modeDropdown.children().contains(name).click();
  }
});
```